# Is it ok to change my question title completely, to refer the general issue instead of occurrences of that issue

Tags: discussion, title

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5122532/string-indexof-chrome-vs-ff) 10 months ago, when I was experiencing an accent problem of the Turkish uppercase i with point: `İ`

The current title is just an example of how the issue occurs: `String.indexOf(..) chrome vs ff`

However the issue is:`Chrome and Safari handles utf 8 differently then Firefox and IE if utf 8 character not hard coded issue?`

From time to time, I see some Q&A's that are about this , like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8550491/facebook-api-unicode-character-in-google-chrome-and-ie).

So is it ok to completely change the question title?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think the only rule should be:

> Does the change to the question invalidate the answers?

If the answer is "no" then go ahead.

If the answer is "yes" then perhaps what should happen is that you ask a more generalised question and then the **original** gets closed as duplicate of the new one. However, that would be up to the community in the first instance, or a moderator agreeing with any flags that might be raised on the question.

Answer (score 2):

If you are **asking the same thing** but in a clearer way, do the change.

If you are **asking a different thing** and are not interested anymore in your original question, vote to close the latter and create a new one.