# Is it OK to ask and answer a general question?

Tags: discussion, self-answer, too-broad, troubleshooting

I was getting a certain error for a while. It took long reads and days to fix it. This error could have several causes, and I learned a few of them fixing mine.

So, I was thinking about asking and answering a question to group some causes and fixes in a single thread. However, doing that will cause me to ask a general question, *"What are some causes and fixes for this error?"*, which could be downvoted/closed for being too broad.

Is it fine if I do that? I think that would be helpful for other people.

*(Note that my meta question is somewhat similar to [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116470/is-it-ok-to-change-my-question-title-completely-to-refer-the-general-issue-inst), except that that one is about **changing** a question, not asking a new one.)*

Comment: You probably want to ask _this_ question on the per-site Meta for the site where you're considering adding your self-answered question.

Comment: see also [I don't always answer myself, but when I do, I fail to ask a good question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188687/i-dont-always-answer-myself-but-when-i-do-i-fail-to-ask-a-good-question)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is it fine if I do that?

No.  The question is too broad, as you yourself acknowledged.

That you intend to answer the question yourself in no way changes the quality standards of the question.  The question needs to be just as appropriate with your answer as it would be if you didn't post an answer.

Comment: Ah, I see ; thanks! So, if I _really_ wanted to post the causes and fixes, I should makes several question instances, and then answer those?

Comment: @AnthonyD. If the questions would be quality questions on their own, sure.  Writing those questions in such a way that they would actually be good questions wouldn't be easy though.